# Poor HTML and Preview Quality

Tags: html, reporting-services

I have a quality issue, when previewing a SSRS report and after deployment to Reporting Server and subsequent viewing of the report via Internet Explorer.

The quality of the Report is really poor, the resolution is of really low quality.

I am really starting to doubt if I made the right choice in moving to SSRS.

Any idea on how to improve this?

[Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxafk.png)

Comment: Just because you can do 3D rendering of a pie chart, doesn't mean you should. :)

Comment: haha I hear you... but even the text is of very poor quality. (after all it should look good)

Comment: Have you tried resizing the chart to see if making it a bit bigger might help with the look? I have never had great luck with the look and feel of SSRS charts, so I tend to avoid them, of go with a flat presentation when I do.